# Does the setting that users blocking registration with the Google Calendar API exist?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Does the setting that users blocking registration with the Google Calendar API exist?

I am considering using the Google Calendar API.
If there is a setting to block registration by API on the user side, the user will not notice schedules.
I want to avoid such a situation.
Please tell me whether there is any setting.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question and try to be more clear what you are trying to do and what you have done to try and solve your problem.

Comment: @DaImTo 
Sorry, I questioned it although I do not research API's specification.
If I will have a chance to ask again, I will research what I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll have to check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth), it was stated in steps 3 to 5.

> 1. When you create your application, you register it using the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Google
>      then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a
>      client secret.
> 2. Activate the Google Calendar API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
> 3. **When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.**
> 4. **Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.**
> 5. **If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.gives your application a short-lived access token.**
> 6. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
> 7. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

Comment: Thank you.

I understood that users set authorization when it is used for the first time, not in advance setting.
I am sorry that my question was bad.
I will consider using API.